# angular file upload in ng-repeat with preview input bind

Tags: angularjs, file, input, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm working on an angular 1.6 based image upload with ng-repeat, note the input is not multi, but there are multiple ng-repeated inputs, I have the image preview working as well as adding lines / removing lines, the only thing that seems to not be working is if I remove an item the file inputs do not update (I have code that does properly update the previews). Here is what I am working with:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in data.items track by $index">
    <input ng-model="item.fileinput" type="file" name="image_{{$index}}" id="image_{{$index}}" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().imageChoose(this)"/><i ng-click="removeEvent($index)" class="fa fa-trash fa-lg"></i>
    <img ng-if="!item.thumb" class="preview-image-small" ng-src="/images/general/placeholder.jpg"</img>
    <img ng-if="item.thumb" class="preview-image-small" ng-src="{{item.thumb}}"</img>
</div>
```

Then in my controller I handle the imageChoose as follows:

```
$scope.imageChoose = function (data) {
var id = data.id.split("_");
id = id[id.length-1];
var elem = document.getElementById(data.id);
if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        $scope.data.data.items[id].thumb = e.target.result;
    });
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(elem.files[0]);
} else {
    alert("This browser does not support FileReader.");
}
};
```

This properly sets the image previews and when I run a remove on a line they re-order correctly due to the ng-src of event.thumb. The problem is the actual file input does not bind or update, here is the code for removing a line:

```
$scope.removeEvent = function (index) {
$scope.data.items.splice(index, 1);
};
```

I'm hoping there is a relatively simple way to bind the input or handle the remove so that the inputs stay correct. Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Comment: I didn't fully understand your issue, but saving data on a dom object is not really the angular way of doing it. anyway, sorry if im been a little bit off topic, but why dont you just use a module that has solved most of those issues like ng-upload? https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload

Comment: That library looks very clean/nice, do you know if it supports ng-repeat by chance... oh my issue is the "removeEvent" removes the line as it should the image preview stays correctly updated, but the image input is not bound and does not update properly.

Comment: not sure about ng-repeat, but I can't think of any reason it won't work with it. been using this specific package for a long time, hasn't failed me so far

Comment: what do you mean by "the input is not bound"? a jsfiddle would really help here

Comment: @BenYitzhaki, sorry, there was some problems with my sample code, I updated it, see ng-model="item.fileinput" this does not bind or change when I select an image... Oh, also I will take a look at the library you mentioned above, will take me some time to implement, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: in what point are you populating the item.fileinput? didn't see it in the js method (maybe you meant the thumb property?). anyway, once you are using a method like $apply, $compile, angular.element - be noticed that you are probably not doing things right. try keeping it simple

Comment: Im not populating it, other then if angular supported it, which it doesn't, it would auto populate based on the fact I am using ng-model. I know it does not support it, so I'm looking for a workaround, I do think your suggestion of a library is good though, I will take a look at that.

Comment: Your `removeEvent` method may nit work because you are using `track by $index` in your `ng-repeat`. [There was a known issue.](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/7119) Try removing it and see if it helps.

Comment: @StanislavKvitash, that was it! Please turn your comment into an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `removeEvent` method is not working because of using `track by $index` together with [`ng-repeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat). [This is a known side effect](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/7119). Try removing it/using [different `track by` expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#tracking-and-duplicates).

Comment: This solved the problem, thanks! Also thanks to Ben for the alternate library suggestion which I may end up checking out for better/smoother integration.